# Ansible: Issues when importing boolean from json file

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I want to use a json file for user management in ansible. Therefore I created a json file containing all the user and groups like this (user_group_management.json):

```json
{
  "linux_users": [
    {
      "name": "myuser",
      "uid": 1003,
      "group": "myuser",
      "groups": "users,sudo",
      "shell": "/bin/bash",
      "password": <password as sha-512>,
      "create_home": "yes",
      "home": "/home/user",
      "hosts": ["hostname1","hostname2","hostname3"]
    },
    {...},
    ...
  ],
  "linux_groups": [...],
}
```

Now I wrote an ansible script for adding the users and groups (user_group_management.yml):

```
- name: User and group management
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - user_group_management.json

  tasks:

  [part for adding groups (no problems here)]

  - name: Add users
    ignore_errors: yes
    user:
      name: item.name
      uid: item.uid
      group: item.group
      groups: item.groups
      shell: item.shell
      password: item.password
      create_home: item.create_home
      home: item.home
      state: present
    when: ansible_hostname in item.hosts
    loop: "{{ linux_users }}"
```

When running the ansible script using `ansible-playbook --check user_management.yml` I get these error messages concerning the "Add users" task:

```
"msg": "The value 'item.create_home' is not a valid boolean.  Valid booleans include: 0, 'on', 'f', 'false', 1, 'no', 'n', '1', '0', 't', 'y', 'off', 'yes', 'true'"
```

I tried to fix this issue by replacing `"create_home": "yes",` with `"create_home": 1,` but it did not change anything. Now I added curly brackets around the variable (`item.create_home` -> `"{{ item.create_home }}"`) which solved the issue. So now I do not get any error messages again.

Sadly I do not understand why this helped me. I thought that `item.create_home` is a string ("yes") in the first place and should be an integer (1) after editing the json file. But both give me the errors. Is there an explanation for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If don't have a lot of experience with json manipulation in ansible however have you tried to change

```
"create_home": "yes",
```

to

```
"create_home": true,
```

Another solution it to convert the value you expect to be boolean with a jinja filter `|bool` when using it.

The [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id6) provides

```
- debug:
    msg: test
  when: some_string_value | bool
```

as an example with `when` condition.

For your case it should be

```
 create_home: item.create_home
```

should become

```
 create_home: "{{ item.create_home | bool }}"
```

**general advice**: You should enclose your variables inside `"{{ }}"`

Comment: Replacing `"yes"` with `true`  did not help. But adding the filter did (although I don't need them when using the brackets). Do you know what the variable type of `item.create_home` (without brackets) is in my script?

Comment: I assume this is taken as a string

Comment: Note that he didn't replace `"yes"` with `"true"`, he replaced it with `true`, which is a boolean value and should work without filters.  But using a filter can help if you can't trust your input data to actually contain the correct data types.